# Unique key in moongose db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following DB:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("556da79a77f9f7465943ff93"),
        "guid" : "a12345",
        "update_day" : "12:05:10 02.06.15"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("556dc4509a0a6a002f97e972"),
        "guid" : "bbbb",
        "update_day" : "15:03:10 02.06.15"
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("556dc470e57836242f5519eb"),
        "guid" : "bbbb",
        "update_day" : "15:03:10 02.06.15"
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("556dc47c7e882d3c2fe9e0fd"),
        "guid" : "bbbb",
        "update_day" : "15:03:10 02.06.15"
        "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to set the guid to be unique, so no to duplicate is possible (Like primary key in MYSQL). So the DB will look like this:

```
   {
            "_id" : ObjectId("556da79a77f9f7465943ff93"),
            "guid" : "a12345",
            "update_day" : "12:05:10 02.06.15"
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("556dc4509a0a6a002f97e972"),
            "guid" : "bbbb",
            "update_day" : "15:03:10 02.06.15"
            "__v" : 0
    }
```

and when I will insert another "guid":"bbbb" (with the save command), it will fails.

Comment: use [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to deal with the current state of your MongoDB collection and delete all the duplicated documents.

One thing is sure : you won't be able to create the unique index with duplicates in your collection and `dropDupes` is now deprecated since the [version 2.7.5](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index) so you can't use it. By the way, it was removed because it was almost impossible to predict which document would be deleted in the process.

Two possible solutions :

1. Create a new collection. Create the unique index on this new collection and run a batch to copy all the documents from the old collection to the new one and make sure you ignore `duplicated key error` during the process.
2. Deal with it in your own collection manually :

   - make sure you won't insert more duplicated documents in your code,
   - run a batch on your collection to delete the duplicates (and make sure you keep the good one if they are not completely identical),
   - then add the unique index.

I would declare my guid like so in [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html) :

`guid : { type : String, unique : true}`

Comment: Important clarification about the existing collection. I created a new collection, and issue was solved (with defining the unique key).

Answer (score 3):

While declaring schema in mongoose, do this

`guid : { type : String, unique : true}`

AND if you want mongodb to create the `guid` on its own (like `_id`) then do this

`guid : { type : String, index : { unique : true} }`

Comment: This is the right way to go, but the second example is equivalent to the first one and won't prompt mongo to create `guid` strings for you like you're implying.